# Can find be used to get the found line and next three lines

Tags: cmd

Can I pipe the results of a command into find and get the next three lines as well?

For example, `gpresult /z` returns the type of group policy and is followed by a Key name, Value and State. `gpresult /z | find "IE Advanced Settings" > gp.txt` will send just the line actually has that string. I would like to get all four of those lines sent to a file instead of just the line that find sends.

If I need to resort to a batch file to do this, I guess that's fine, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
    'Remove ^ from quoting command line. Quote, ampersand and brackets
    Pttn = Replace(Arg(1), "^(", "(")
    Pttn = Replace(Pttn, "^)", ")")
    Pttn = Replace(Pttn, "^&", "&")
    Pttn = Replace(Pttn, "^""", """")
    Set regEx1 = New RegExp
    If Instr(LCase(Arg(0)), "i") > 0 then
        regEx1.IgnoreCase = True
    Else
        regEx1.IgnoreCase = False
    End If 
    If Instr(LCase(Arg(0)), "v") > 0 then
        IncExc = False
    Else
        IncExc = True
    End If 
    regEx1.Global = False
    regEx1.Pattern = Pttn 
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        Line=Inp.readline
        If RegEx1.Test(Line) = IncExc then
            outp.writeline Line
            Outp.writeline Inp.Readline
            Outp.writeline Inp.Readline
            Outp.writeline Inp.Readline
        End If
    Loop
```

To use

```
cscript //nologo GetThreeLines.vbs i "console" < Filter.bat
```

This is an example, the echo lines are what was found.

```
C:\Users\David Candy\Desktop>cscript //nologo GetThreeLines.vbs i "console" < Fi    lter.bat
echo     trimming console output and text files.
echo.
echo     Filter.bat makes Filter.vbs easily usable from the command line. It
echo     controls unicode/ansi support and debugging.
```

**SearchOptions**

```
i - ignore case
v - include non-matching lines
n - none
```

Ampersands and brackets in expression must be escaped with the caret. Do not escape carets. Use hexidecimal code \x22 for quotes.

To extract all section headers starting with a lower case letter

```
filter filter n "\[[a-z].+" < "%systemroot%\win.ini"
```

This shows the caret escaping an opening bracket for CMD.EXE and the backslash escaping the opening bracket for the RegEx engine

```
filter filter n "\^(" < "%systemroot%\win.ini"
```

This shows searching for a quote character

```
filter filter n "\x22" < "%systemroot%\win.ini"
```

**Regular Expressions Reference**
*From the Windows Vista SDK, VBScript Language Reference © Microsoft Corp 2006*

```
Character Description 
\ Marks the next character as either a special character or a literal. For example, "n" matches the character "n". "\n" matches a newline character. The sequence "\\" matches "\" and "\(" matches "(". 
^ Matches the beginning of input. 
$ Matches the end of input. 
* Matches the preceding character zero or more times. For example, "zo*" matches either "z" or "zoo". 
+ Matches the preceding character one or more times. For example, "zo+" matches "zoo" but not "z". 
? Matches the preceding character zero or one time. For example, "a?ve?" matches the "ve" in "never". 
. Matches any single character except a newline character. 
(pattern) Matches pattern and remembers the match. The matched substring can be retrieved from the resulting Matches collection, using Item [0]...[n]. To match parentheses characters ( ), use "\(" or "\)". 
x|y Matches either x or y. For example, "z|wood" matches "z" or "wood". "(z|w)oo" matches "zoo" or "wood". 
{n} n is a nonnegative integer. Matches exactly n times. For example, "o{2}" does not match the "o" in "Bob," but matches the first two o's in "foooood". 
{n,} n is a nonnegative integer. Matches at least n times. For example, "o{2,}" does not match the "o" in "Bob" and matches all the o's in "foooood." "o{1,}" is equivalent to "o+". "o{0,}" is equivalent to "o*". 
{ n , m } m and n are nonnegative integers. Matches at least n and at most m times. For example, "o{1,3}" matches the first three o's in "fooooood." "o{0,1}" is equivalent to "o?". 
[ xyz ] A character set. Matches any one of the enclosed characters. For example, "[abc]" matches the "a" in "plain". 
[^ xyz ] A negative character set. Matches any character not enclosed. For example, "[^abc]" matches the "p" in "plain". 
[ a-z ] A range of characters. Matches any character in the specified range. For example, "[a-z]" matches any lowercase alphabetic character in the range "a" through "z". 
[^ m-z ] A negative range characters. Matches any character not in the specified range. For example, "[m-z]" matches any character not in the range "m" through "z". 
\b Matches a word boundary, that is, the position between a word and a space. For example, "er\b" matches the "er" in "never" but not the "er" in "verb". 
\B Matches a non-word boundary. "ea*r\B" matches the "ear" in "never early". 
\d Matches a digit character. Equivalent to [0-9]. 
\D Matches a non-digit character. Equivalent to [^0-9]. 
\f Matches a form-feed character. 
\n Matches a newline character. 
\r Matches a carriage return character. 
\s Matches any white space including space, tab, form-feed, etc. Equivalent to "[ \f\n\r\t\v]". 
\S Matches any nonwhite space character. Equivalent to "[^ \f\n\r\t\v]". 
\t Matches a tab character. 
\v Matches a vertical tab character. 
\w Matches any word character including underscore. Equivalent to "[A-Za-z0-9_]". 
\W Matches any non-word character. Equivalent to "[^A-Za-z0-9_]". 
\num Matches num, where num is a positive integer. A reference back to remembered matches. For example, "(.)\1" matches two consecutive identical characters. 
\ n Matches n, where n is an octal escape value. Octal escape values must be 1, 2, or 3 digits long. For example, "\11" and "\011" both match a tab character. "\0011" is the equivalent of "\001" & "1". Octal escape values must not exceed 256. If they do, only the first two digits comprise the expression. Allows ASCII codes to be used in regular expressions. 
\xn Matches n, where n is a hexadecimal escape value. Hexadecimal escape values must be exactly two digits long. For example, "\x41" matches "A". "\x041" is equivalent to "\x04" & "1". Allows ASCII codes to be used in regular expressions.
```

**An Improved Version**

To use

```
cscript //nologo GetLines.vbs searchoptions linecount "searchstring"
```

eg

```
cscript //nologo GetLines.vbs i 3 "Fonts" < %windir%\win.ini
```

*GetLines.vbs*

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
    'Remove ^ from quoting command line. Quote, ampersand and brackets
    Pttn = Replace(Arg(2), "^(", "(")
    Pttn = Replace(Pttn, "^)", ")")
    Pttn = Replace(Pttn, "^&", "&")
    Pttn = Replace(Pttn, "^""", """")
    Set regEx1 = New RegExp
    If Instr(LCase(Arg(0)), "i") > 0 then
        regEx1.IgnoreCase = True
    Else
        regEx1.IgnoreCase = False
    End If 
    If Instr(LCase(Arg(0)), "v") > 0 then
        IncExc = False
    Else
        IncExc = True
    End If 
    regEx1.Global = False
    regEx1.Pattern = Pttn 
    Count = Arg(1)
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        Line=Inp.readline
        If RegEx1.Test(Line) = IncExc then
            outp.writeline Line
            For x = 0 to count - 1
                Outp.writeline Inp.Readline
            Next
        End If
    Loop
```